# System.Threading.Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

i am trying to use that reference. i know it is in c# 4. i don't know what i currently have.

but basically, when i write the line:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(someMethod);
```

it tells me that it is a mistake. is there any way to solve it so my ide will identify that library (Task Parallel Library)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just need a using directive of

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

You shouldn't need to add any extra references - [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) is in mscorlib.

Are you sure you're targeting .NET 4? Check in your project properties. (The types available don't depend on the version of the *language* you're using, but the version of the *framework* you're using.)

Comment: but even when i type that namespace , when i try to use Task , it wont give me its name (in the automatic name generating drop list).. why is that?

Comment: The link you provide to Task states that this is used in .NET 4.5, so I'm assuming this isn't possible in 4.0? You're question asking if he's targeting .NET 4 is throwing me of.

Comment: @djerry: You didn't look at the documentation carefully enough: under version information, "Supported in: 4.5, 4". (Look at when I wrote this answer - back in February 2011, *long* before .NET 4.5 was available.)

Answer (score 7):

You can see what framework version you're targeting by right-clicking your project and selecting Properties. On the Application tab, your framework version will be in the "Target framework" dropdown. If there is no Application tab, check for a Silverlight tab.

If you are targeting .NET 4, then `Task` is already referenced; see Jon's answer.

If you are targeting .NET 3.5, then you can get `Task` by downloading [Microsoft Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896) and adding those libraries as references.

If you are targeting .NET 2 or Silverlight, then you're out of luck; `Task` is not available on those systems.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a reference to an earlier version of mscorlib.  Make sure you have the 4.0 version.  If you have an earlier one referenced (like 2.x), delete the reference and add the one for 4.0.

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure your code looks something like this

```
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => pr.DoSomething());
```

Please share your code if the issue still persists.