# Downgrading target platform from 4.5 to 3.5 causing assembly troubles

Tags: c#, winforms

I was downgrading the target platform to 3.5 from 4.5. I got alot of faults, and the biggest contributers is

- System.Threading.Tasks (where task cannot be found).
- Microsoft.CSharp

These two, I dont know how to handle. Please help!

Comment: Please, give me a hint on how to do this. Construct? How can I backtrack and see what functions i've used the required this assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of those namespaces were introduced in .NET 4.0, so you'll have to replace them if you're going to target 3.5.

Regarding `System.Threading.Tasks`, [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050004/system-threading-tasks) has some good answers and alternatives for targeting 3.5.

As for the `Microsoft.CSharp` reference, look for the use of the `dynamic` keyword in your code. If you're not using it, you can probably just forget it.